# Javascript only running half of loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I am using Node.js and I have a loop that looks like this:

```
var request = require('request');

for(var i = 0; i< some_number; i++){
 console.log(i); 
 request( url.concat(i), function(error, response, body){
 if(!error){console.log("ABC" + i)}
 else{
 console.log(error);
 });

}
```

and it returns  `0` to `some_number-1` before running `request`, and I'm not sure what's going on. I am using the [request module](https://github.com/request/request).

Comment: your some_function is async

Comment: @Tushar edited, and Juvian, I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: An asynchronous interface allows the script to continue running while it does its work and calls a callback function when it’s done. This is the way Node does all its I/O. You might find [this chapter](http://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html) interesting. Working with Node, without having any idea of what async is seems wrong.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and yeah, I know- I just needed to do some web scraping and it seemed like the right tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a request, it takes time to return, but the loop does not wait for it, it keeps going. This asynchronous nature is one of Javascript main principles.

If you want to wait for each request before continuing the loop, maybe try something like this:

```
function iterator(i) {
  if (i < some_number) {
    request(url.concat(i), function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      iterator(i + 1);
    });
  }
}
// Kick off the loop
iterator(0);
```

Comment: `iterator` is just what I named the function, it is essentially a synchronous `for` loop. Inside the `if` statement is what get's executed each time through.